# How to make a function only work on first body onload?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, forms

I have a classifieds website, and when users first enter the website a form is submitted on body onload event:

The form is submitted and displays its results in an iframe on the same page.

The problem is that I dont want the submit_form() function to be called everytime the user clicks back or forward in the browser, so how can I prevent the browser from submitting it when using back/forward buttons?

Example:

Form submits when user enters site.
Form shows Search Results in an iframe 
User clicks one of the results and new page is displayed 
User hits back button to go to the search results again 
User finds the form has been resubmitted again, because of body onload triggers

How should I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: @Chinmayee Why did you remove php and mysql from the tags? I think they were relevant.

Comment: this question is generic & can be applied to any language like java, .net. Also database technology is irrelevant to this question. 3rd we can have 5 tags for any question so I thought session/cookie are more relevant tags than php & mysql

Comment: @Chinmayee How do you know that he wants session or cookie? They do have some relevance, but having php and mysql there is more helpful because you know he would consider a server side and/or db approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client side only solution: Set a [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

Comment: for people who disables cookies you could make a fallback over the URL (like giving a parameter ?fristrun=true)

Answer (score 0):

you tagged this question with php so I think is better using server side session

- start a session, init a session varto 0

Form submits when user enters site.

- if session var == 0 then show results

Form shows Search Results in an iframe

- set session var to 1

User clicks one of the results and new page is displayed
User hits back button to go to the search results again

- this doesn't happen:

User finds the form has been resubmitted again, because of body onload triggers

Comment: Wouldn't the submit still happen, only php doesn't return a response? I think solution needs to be client/cookie based to stop the submit in the first place..

Comment: ok, a cookie will work as well. I simply control the session on second page